# Access properties in App.xaml.cs from different project UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Like what I said in the title, how can we access the property in App in a different project? I want to access it from normal class like a service. Not in viewmodel. Hope we can do something like **Application as App.**

Answer (score 1):

> Access properties in App.xaml.cs from different project UWP

You may try to use one `App.xaml.cs` for the two projects. For example, if the second project wants to access `App.xaml.cs` in the first project without reference the first project, you may consider remove the `App.xaml.cs` which is belonged to the second project, and `Add-ExitingItem` to add the `App.xaml.cs` from the first project. In that case, the two projects will share the same `App.xam.cs` and then you can directly access the properties as Marian Dolinský mentioned.

Otherwise, the two projects may not be able to communicate with each other directly. If the above method is not suit for you, please detail why you need this feature and we may need to consider other ways without accessing the `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: Hi. Should we use `Add-ExitingItem` way? Is it good practice or not?

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

You could cast `Application.Current` to `App`:

```
App app = (App)Application.Current;
app.YourProperty = something;
```

## Method 2

Create some static property holding the reference of `App`. In my projects I do it by creating a new property called `Current` as follows:

```
// in App.xaml.cs
public static new App Current { get; private set; }

public App()
{
    Current = this;
    // Another code
}
```

Comment: Because I'm in the different project so I cannot do like method 1. and 2. My second project doesn't have reference to App.xaml.cs project